# Does UFT or QTP support Windows 10?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

We are planning to test our application on Windows 10. We got UFT 12 & QTP 11 & want to know whether it supports windows 10 or not.

I tried to search on google but didnt get clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

It supports windows 10. We already tested this with our UFT scripts.You go ahead and start.Good luck:)

Answer (score 3):

QTP 11 is ancient, it doesn't support Windows 10 (or 8 for that matter).

UFT supports Windows 10 beginning with [version 12.51](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Application-Lifecycle-Management/The-first-service-pack-for-LeanFT-and-UFT-is-now-available-Get/ba-p/6798472#.Vh4U_fmqpBe), however Microsoft Edge isn't supported (at the time this answer is written).

Comment: Thanks for your reply... We tested our application on windows 10 using UFT 12.02 & its working fine.

Comment: There's experimental support from 12.02 but official support is only from 12.50 as you can see in the blog I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Installed UFT 11.5 successfully on Windows 10 using "Run as Administrator".
The application opened fine.